# Styling linking titles

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On my side, i want all links in texts etc to be red.

All headlines should be black.

AND All **linking** headlines should be black as well.

**Problem**: As soon as I set ...

```
a:link {color:#d11112; text-decoration: none;}
```

...all my linking headlines turn red as well.

*How do I keep them black?*

Here is my headline css:

```
h2  { font-size:18px; line-height:23px; color:#000000; padding:0px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;  text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to add

```
h2 a { color:000000; }
```

somewhere after

```
a:link {color:#d11112; text-decoration: none;}
```

Also, lose the `:link`, as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). This lets you select only elements based on the value of a specific attribute or attributes. Therefore, to select only `<a>` elements you're using as anchors, you could try something that selects `<a>`s with an id but not a href, or something like that.

For instance, you could have this rule:

```
a:not([href]) {
    color: black;
}
```

However, it wouldn't be compatible with IE 6 (then again, what is?)

Answer (score 0):

Just so you're aware, when you do a:link this is setting the color for an unvisited link.

You need to set the color for the a element inside of your h2 tags.

So you need to change it to:

```
 h2 a { font-size:18px; line-height:23px; color:#000000; padding:0px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;  text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS works in a nested way, so assuming your `<a>` tags are within the `<h2>`, that is:

```html
<h2>
<a href="...">...</a>
</h2>
```

it'll apply first the `<h2>` styles and then the `<a>` styles, so you end up with red links. However, you can make it apply the h2 CSS to those links as well by using CSS selectors instead of just the h2 tags, for example:

`h2, h2 > a {[your style here]}`

where `h2 > a` means `<a>` tags nested within an `<h2>`.